# Correlation/distance between sparse vectors

Tags: correlation, distance, sparse, spearmans-rank-correlation

I am looking for a metric for comparing gene count tables. These are long columns of data (a few millions genes by a few dozen samples), with all non-negative entries, about 90% of which are zeros. The goal is to compare the performance of several tools/algorithms that these tables originate from, by comparing the resulting tables among themselves or with the expected counts (in a case of sumulates data). In principle, one compares on a sample-by-sample basis, but comparing different samples might be also of interest, e.g., to filter out spurious correlations.

What I am using now is Spearman rank coefficient, taking account for the fact that some entries have identical ranks (certainly the zeros). I am looking for an approach more adapted to this setting (and preferably robust to outliers) and will appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to mind is a similarity measure such as cosine. It's often used with sparse vectors (text represented as vectors over the vocabulary).
There are many options for distance/similarity measures:

- Basic set measures like overlap coefficient or Jaccard
- Entropy-based measures such as [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence).
- ...

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am not sure, if Jaccard has good generalizations to non-boolean vectors... As for Entropy-based measures (like mutual information), they are not very robust (although I forgot to mention this is my question).

Comment: @Vadim there are variants of Jaccard for non-boolean vectors, but in general all these measures will give pretty similar results: cosine, euclidean distance, Jaccard, etc. The question of which measure makes sense in your task depends on the data, but for that you're the expert ;) For example Spearman correlation focuses on the rank between the values in the vector, so it doesn't take into account the values themselves (e.g. [2,100,67] would obtain perfect Spearman correlation with [20,22,21])